# Upload a .mat file to stack overflow for the purpose of illustration

Tags: discussion

How do I attach a .mat (or csv or any other variant) file to a question in Stackoverflow.

The questions I want to ask requires this for illustration.

Comment: Don't know what a `.mat` file is -- but the toolbar in the "question editor" has the ability to insert pictures and links -- don't think data files are allowed -- include a minimum amount of test data in text form with the question if relevant.

Comment: A .mat is a Matlab data file. The question was originally posted in Stack Overflow with the "Matlab" tag, although actually it's quite general, not specific to any language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it in Stack Overflow directly (for general files). Use some external web for that (such as http://www.speedyshare.com/ or http://www.zippyshare.com/), and link that file in your question. The toolbar has a button for inserting links.

If possible, I suggest you avoid using files that way, to save time. Sometimes it's enough to paste a small part of the file directly in the question (if that part of the file does reproduce the problem). Of course, if the actual file is necessary, go ahead.

For images you can do it within Stack Overflow: just use the "image" button that appears in the toolbar while editing the question.

Comment: The problem with this is that the links can expire. Images can be hosted on SE's imgur space exactly for this reason, they don't expire there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luis Mendo's answer, I would like to point out the concept of a [short, self contained, correct (compilable) example](http://sscce.org/).
The question you should be asking yourself is: Do those that want to help me need

- all of the code that I just posted?
- all of my data?

Or could you rather condense your code (e.g. plotting the manipulated data may have nothing to do with the question, changing all figure properties may be unrelated to the original plotting issue, etc.)? Could you provide a matrix of random that is sufficient to illustrate why a certain operation fails, etc.